# stuck on a useless lumia 525 with windows 10 mobile's buggy insider preview

Tags: store, windows-10-mobile, nokia-lumia-525

i have a lumia 525 with windows phone 10 insider preview, i couldn't install the latest preview and am stuck in a buggy one, whatever, i reseted it to factory settings yesterday and there is only 5 apps on the app list, no phone dial, no marketplace, no settings nothing, so i wanted to downgrade it to 8.1 using the windows recovery tool and it said that no package available for the Lumia 525, so please...please...please... if someone knows what to do walk me through.

Comment: Hi ! did you use the LATEST version of Windows Device Recovery Tool, that you can find there : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA142987 ?

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, with Lumia 525, I updated to W 10 insider preview, on Reset i got only 5 - 7 apps, I had to go to Microsoft care and repair it.
I think there is no way out except Microsoft Care.